# Sempahores and Mutex Lock

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

What is the difference between these two scenarios? I cannot understand which to use. It seems that they basically do the same thing.

```
pthread_lock(&mutex)
critical section
pthread_unlock(&mutex)
```

vs

```
sem_wait(&mutex)
section
sem_post(&mutex)
```

Comment: One of these is 1 thread-at-a-time mutual exclusion . A semaphore, in general,  can allow several threads to access the critical section

Answer (score 2):

What other answers forget to mention is that semaphores does not have "owners". Mutex usually have an owner of a lock, so that only the thread that locks it can also unlock it. Semaphores are just counters.

Comment: Also one thread can acquire a mutex more than once. It needs to release that mutex the same number of times before another thread can acquire it.

Answer (score 1):

Mutex allows only one thread at a time to access the critical section.

Semaphores allow more exotic concurrency. For example solving the readers and writers problem - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem

Answer (score 1):

Mutexes are generally binary whereas semaphores can be initialized to values greater than 1. In practice this means that more than one thread could hold a lock on a semaphore concurrently while that is impossible with a mutex. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes mutexes provide priority escalation to prevent priority inversion and semaphores don't. In my RTOS that is the prime reason I choose one over the other.